# Как в SQL запросе задать условие "не позднее N даты"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Такая задача:

> Выбрать все ВКТ-7 созданные с 23.04.2020-15.08.2020 и активированные не позднее двух месяцев

Выбрать записи с `BETWEEN` - не проблема:

```
WHERE (DeviceBase.DeviceCode = 20002) 
AND (ConnectedDeviceBase.CreatedOn BETWEEN '23.04.2020 00:00:00' 
                                       AND '15.08.2020 00:00:00')
```

Но вот второе условие - "не позднее двух месяцев" - уже не могу понять. В гугле особо ответов не получил.

Comment: толкование сложных бюрократических оборотов — это не совсем о программировании, и совсем не об sql. скорее всего, в задании подразумевалось, что между созданием и активацией прошло меньше или ровно два месяца.

Comment: так мне просто нужно условие типа "не позднее N даты", разве такого нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос - вы можете воспользоваться функцией [DATEDIFF(...)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
WHERE ...
  and datediff(month, CreatedOn, ActivatedOn) <= 2
```

Comment: Да, спасибо за помощь, запомню.